# Spoof WiFi settings as 'On' but use Cellular Data (for specific apps or in total)

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-note-4

*Alternatively*, can android force an app to use Cellular data?

**The app in question:** Amazon Video [Version 3.0.57.30110 "Prime Video for Android Software"]

**Device in use:**Samsung Galaxy Note 4 - Android Version: 5.0.1 Build LRX22C.N910TUVU1COG2 (USA TMobile Completely Stock, No Root etc)

**Issue:** AV doesn't allow 'download for offline viewing' of media larger than 50mb in size. The app wants to see the device is connected to a WiFi network to allow downloads.

**Why this is an issue:** When travelling, I use my unlimited network to download media for offline use when leaving network coverage areas (wilderness, trains/planes etc) - with an unlimited cellular plan, I don't care about what size file I'm downloading; Amazon is undoubtedly attempting to help users from inadvertently maxing out their data plans and blaming Amazon in the process (yes, those users exist)...

Interestingly, a cellular hotspot will allow download - as the app see's the device as being on a WiFi Network.

**Restating the Question:**
Is there a way to either, force the app into using cellular data, or, spoof the phone's wifi state as 'on' but use cellular data anyway?

Research:
Reading other threads, this problem is unique in the sense that wifi is not an option to use - assume i only have cellular data; how can i use apps that request wifi for their functions?

Answer (score 1):

In order to simulate a wifi connection on 3g/4g (assuming you are rooted), you additionally need **Xposed framework** installed and install [Hack connectivity service tool](https://android-apk.org/org.tracetool.hackconnectivityservice/).

You then choose wifi and activate traces

See below:

[image: hack tool]

This module forces the Connectivity manager  to return Wi-Fi networking info as active.

An alternative tool (if Hack connectivity service module is not working) is [Fake Wi-Fi Connection](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.lemonsqueeze.fakewificonnection) module try v1.9 (beta) for lollipop+. Sometimes some applications won't work when no Wi-Fi is detected so it simulates  an active Wi-Fi connection in order for apps to get internet. It uses the same concept as the above tool.

Edit:

Another suggested option is to decompile the apk file and make

> network connectivity check always return true.

Hope this helps